# Throw IOException instead of Exception

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I have method1() which is called from lots of other methods throughout the code. This is the signature of the method:

```
 public void method1(final Properties properties) throws IOException {}
```

All methods calling this method also throw IOException.

The actual code in method1() changed, so now instead of IOException it throws some other exceptions that extend Exception and ***not*** IOException anymore.

I don’t want to change the signature of all methods calling method1().

Is it ok to create IOException and still throw IOException from method1() and hence the methods calling method1()?

Something like below:

```
 Try {
  // code
 } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new IOException(e.getCause());
 }
```

Comment: that would work, but it looks quite dirty to me, as you are loosing the information carried by the type of exception actually thrown.

Comment: When I have e.getCause() and e.getMessage(), don't they give me the actual exception and the information related to that exception?

Comment: I would rather use the `Throwable` constructor : `new IOException(e)` directly, so the root exception can be retrieved using `myIOException.getCause()` when your ioexception is caught. Also, that will print a `caused by` block in the stacktrace, which will help debugging

Comment: If all callers of `method1` also throw `IOException` they don't seem to handle it ad there's little point in declaring the exception at all. If callers are not expected to handle what `method1` throws, why not throw a suitable subtype of `RuntimeException`?

Comment: The callers themselves either handle or throw IOException of their own. You are right, I can change the signature of the all methods - including method1() to throw custom exp. instead, but wanted to avoid the actual code changes related to that. The exp. thrown by method1() however, won't be and should not be handled at all, it will end up in error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the original exception as the cause, so you're not losing the original message or stacktrace. Calling `e.getCause()` in your code example is skipping over the exception that you caught and getting *its* cause, which is suspicious-looking.

Also it would be better to specify the particular exceptions that the method catches, rather than using a catch-all Exception type. Catching Exception would result in things like NullPointerExceptions getting caught that were not trapped before.

The best thing to do here is change the exceptions thrown by your method to a custom type that doesn't let the implementation details bleed through to the callers. Your method signature should change to

```
public void method1(final Properties properties) throws SomeCustomException {
    try {
        .... // do whatever
    } catch (AException | BException | CException e) {
        throw new SomeCustomException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is a really bad idea to do this. No one will get the idea, why an IOException is thrown for a DatabaseException (if migrated from Filesystem to Database).

Comment: @Christian: yes, i misinterpreted the question initially.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, you should **not** do this, because you will confuse every other developer reading your code or reading stacktraces.

From the software-design point of view, the error happened a lot earlier.
If your code is like an API and used by others, you may better have used Custom-Exceptions and wrapped the IOException as root-cause.

If you have the complete source, you should refactor the source and add another exception signature.

Answer (score 0):

This will work technically.

However, catching `Exception` or `Throwable` is almost everytime a bad idea (as is throwing them), because you will also catch all other Exceptions, besides `RuntimeExceptions`.

If you can change the code of all calling classes (i.e. you are not developing a framework/library), you should do so. Because I assume you meant `method1()` throws a more specific type now.

You may also think about throwing a Subtype of `RuntimeException` which does not need to be catched, and is a good idea for errors that can't be corrected (e.g. a bad configuration).
(see *Clean Code* by Robert Martin)

Comment: Right, the exceptions thrown now, are: com.google.api.ads.common.lib.exception.OAuthException AND com.google.api.ads.common.lib.exception.ValidationException I can catch only these two exception instead of Exception. We do have custom Exception as well, the thing is that I did not want to change the signature of all methods calling method1() to throw any other exception instead of IOException.

Comment: If you have all calling classes available in one IDE, it usually is not a big deal...